# Is there any already built way, or any clever way that I could go about converting LaTeX into glsl code?

Tags: javascript, latex, glsl

I'm using LaTeX for a project I'm working on where the input will be in LaTeX form, but I need the LaTeX input to be converted to glsl. The problem is that LaTeX has so many little "edge cases" where the parsing and converting code would be incredibly tedious to hardcode (by hardcode I mean write a bunch of ifs to handle every little case). Is hardcoding every little nuance of LaTeX "grammar" the only way for me to do this?

For example:
This `\sin\left(x^{2^x}\right)` should convert to this `sin(pow(x, pow(2, x))` .

Comment: If you are being given a formula written in Latex, then either you or someone else is going to have to write a Latex parser and generate GLSL code from its results.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it was a foolish question, in truth I think I supposed this was the reality from the start--I just hoped someone had come across a parser or this problem before.